How do I forward signals to a process started with xfvb-run in Docker?
I have some code that I would like to run inside a Docker image with xfvb using xfvb-run. This code has a signal handler that should gracefully exit on SIGTERM when the Docker container receives a SIGTERM (for example through cancelling a google cloud run job).
It seems like my process is not receiving and signals. I am already using tini as an entrypoint in my Dockerfile to handle signaling, as suggested in basically all other questions about this.
Here is some code I am running to debug the behavior:
const sleep = (millis: number): Promise<void> =>
    new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, millis));


export const main = async (): Promise<void> => {

    process.on("SIGTERM", () => {
        console.log("Received sigterm")
        process.exit(1)
    })

    console.log({pid: process.pid})
    let i = 0
    while (true) {
        i++;
        console.log({i}, "sleeping")
        await sleep(1000)
    }
}

This is my Dockerfile:

# ...More setup code to install the typescript code

COPY src ./src
RUN npm i && pnpm build

ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--"]
CMD ["xvfb-run", '-s "-screen 0 1920x1080x8"', "node", "src"]

I am now running the following commands to start and kill the image with SIGTERM:

docker build -t debug:signals .
docker run --rm -t --name killme debug:signals
(new terminal window) docker kill --signal=SIGTERM killme

I'm only getting output like this, notice that the log line about the caught sigterm is missing:
{ pid: 20 }
{ i: 1 } sleeping
{ i: 2 } sleeping
{ i: 3 } sleeping
{ i: 4 } sleeping
{ i: 5 } sleeping
{ i: 6 } sleeping

It then stops once it receives the SIGTERM without the log.
How do I pass the signal to the node process that is running inside xfvb?

You need to build the signal forwarding yourself, xfvb doesn't do it for you.
For this, create a script that starts xvfb in the background, traps the signals and forwards them to children of the xfvb process:
#!/bin/bash

# Start the process with a virtual x server
xvfb-run -s "-screen 0 1920x1080x8" "$@" &

# Get the PID of the background process of the x server
CHILD_PID=$!

forward_signal() {
  # $1 is the signal that is forwarded
  # pgrep -P gives me processes which have the xfvb-run as a parent process
  kill -"$1" $(pgrep -P $CHILD_PID)
}

# Trap the signals you need and forward them
trap 'forward_signal SIGTERM' SIGTERM

# Wait for the xfvb-run process to finish
wait $CHILD_PID

Make it executable and add it to your Dockerfile:
# ...
ENTRYPOINT ["/tini", "--"]
CMD ["./forwardSignals.sh", "node", "src"]

You will now get the desired output by running the docker commands:
{ pid: 17 }
{ i: 1 } sleeping
{ i: 2 } sleeping
{ i: 3 } sleeping
{ i: 4 } sleeping
Received sigterm

